Remove items from list starting with a list of prefixes
I have a list of strings and a list of prefixes. I want to remove all elements from the list of strings that start with a prefix from the list of prefixes.
I used a for loop, but why doesn't it seem to work?
list_of_strings = ['test-1: foo', 'test-2: bar', 'test-3: cat']
list_of_prefixes = ['test1', 'test-2']

final_list = []
for i in list_of_strings:
    for j in list_of_prefixes:
        if not i.startswith(j):
            final_list.append(i)
            
print(list(set(final_list)))

Currently the output is
['test-3: cat', 'test-1: foo', 'test-2: bar']

The output I want to get is
final_list = ['test-3: cat']


Your approach doesn't work because you potentially perform an append for each element in list_of_prefixes, but if the string does start with one of the prefixes, it's guaranteed to not start with one of the others, so they all get added.
With list comprehensions, generator expressions, and any, this is very straightforward.
>>> list_of_strings = ['test-1: foo', 'test-2: bar', 'test-3: cat']
>>> list_of_prefixes = ['test1', 'test-2']
>>> filtered = [
...   s 
...   for s in list_of_strings 
...   if not any(s.startswith(p) for p in list_of_prefixes)
... ]
>>> filtered
['test-1: foo', 'test-3: cat']

Note that 'test-1: foo' does not start with 'test1' or 'test-2'. If you meant for the list_of_prefixes to include 'test-1' then you would get the output you expect.

You can simplify your code. startswith accepts multiple prefixes natively, and will return True if one of them is present. However, that argument needs to be a tuple, not a list, so I renamed it.
list_of_strings = ['test-1: foo', 'test-2: bar', 'test-3: cat']
# switch to a tuple
tuple_of_prefixes = ('test-1', 'test-2')
 
final_list = []
for i in list_of_strings:
    if not i.startswith(tuple_of_prefixes):
        final_list.append(i)
 
print(list(set(final_list)))

(Also, per your exposition, I guess you wanted to exclude test-1, not test1.)
Demo: https://ideone.com/0NvI5z
This can obviously be turned into a list comprehension if you like.

The problem with your implementation is that, for each prefix, you go over the whole list_of_strings and add to the final result final_list all the elements that don't start with that prefix specifically, including strings that may start with other prefixes in list_of_prefixes (which, ultimately, you wouldn't want to keep).
For example:

in the first iteration of list_of_strings, the element is 'test-1: foo', so you iterate over list_of_prefixes, the first prefix is 'test-1'. Cool, you don't add 'test-1: foo' to final_list.
Next prefix now is 'test-2'. You check it against 'test-1: foo', and it passes the check if not i.startswith(j), so you end up adding 'test-1: foo' to final_list anyway!
Same goes on for the next iterations.

As a quick fix for your own implementation, without changing much on your logic, my suggestion is: instead of starting with an empty set and adding to it, start with a set of all the list_of_strings, and go removing the unwanted in your iterations!
Like this:
final_list = set(list_of_strings)
for i in list_of_strings:
    for j in list_of_prefixes:
        if i.startswith(j):
            final_list.remove(i)


Eventually, as you progress in your journey with python, you will learn that most of these basic operations (like filtering) are already covered by the built-in modules. There are many ways to do this without custom loops. For example, using the filter and list comprehensions:
[s for s in list_of_strings if not any(filter(s.startswith, list_of_prefixes))]


You can use startswith() with a flag:
def _filter(list_of_strings, list_of_prefixes):
    final_list = []
    for i in list_of_strings:
        flag = False
        for j in list_of_prefixes:
            if i.startswith(j):
                flag = True
                break
        if not flag:
            final_list.append(i)
    return final_list


list_of_strings = ['test-1: foo', 'test-2: bar', 'test-3: cat']
list_of_prefixes = ['test-1', 'test-2']

print(_filter(list_of_strings, list_of_prefixes))


Prints
['test-3: cat']


You can use a list comprehensive one liner like:
list_of_strings = ['test-1: foo', 'test-2: bar', 'test-3: cat']
list_of_prefixes = ['test1', 'test-2']

new = [x for x in list_of_strings if x.split(':')[0] not in list_of_prefixes]
print(new)

Output:
['test-1: foo', 'test-3: cat']


What a fun puzzle.  I'm assuming the first entry in the prefixes is 'test-1'.
The reason your loop isn't working is that you're effectively starting fresh each time you query and put the resultant into the final array and end up with one of each answer.
As you're effectively filtering down to only what you want to see, you can achieve your goal like this:
list_of_strings = ['test-1: foo', 'test-2: bar', 'test-3: cat']
list_of_prefixes = ['test-1', 'test-2']

final_list = list_of_strings
for prefix in list_of_prefixes:
    result = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(prefix), final_list))
    for ele in result:
        final_list.remove(ele)

print(final_list)

I preserved the original arrays just in case you needed them further in your code.

this code mutates the original lists, final_list = list_of_strings does not make a copy
